# Script to rename specific part of the filename with another file name?

Tags: scripting, regular-expression, rename

**Contents of folder /home/User/Desktop/DR**

```
dr_subject00001_Z.nii
dr_subject00002_Z.nii
dr_subject00003_Z.nii
```

... and so on (increments by 1 up until the number 40)

**Contents of folder /home/User/Desktop/rsfMRI**

```
MCU_0001_01
MCU_0001_03
MCU_0002_03
```

... and so on (these values are random, but they have a RANGE, the 4 digit value can go up to 40 but these values can be repeated (we can have two 0001), and the 2 digits that follow the underscore alternates between 01 and 03).

What I am trying to do is use a match to find the digits "####_##" (4 digits followed by underscore and 2 other digits) from folder rsfMRI and REPLACE and RENAME the "#####" (5 digits in the file name) of DR folder.

So that the **output** would be

```
dr_subject0001_01
dr_subject0001_02
dr_subject0002_03
```

How can I do that?

**Edit:** 
There are the same number of files in both folders. I want it to go through the files in each folder in order so that the first file in DR folder matches first file in rsfMRI folder, and so on.

Comment: So `MCU_0001_01` should match `dr_subject00001_Z.nii` and rename it to `dr_subject0001_01.nii`, correct?  What does `MCU_0001_03` match then?

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes, exactly :) So MCU_0001_03 will match dr_subject00002 and so the renamed file will be dr_subject0001_03.  I want them to match each other in  the order as they are listed in the folder.

Comment: What command are you using to list the folder?

Comment: @Jesse_b I was thinking of putting them all in a text file (with the directories and files listed in the txt file) in order.  But I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: I'm missing something; how are you matching (4 digits _ 2 digits) to a 5-digit filename? Do the just go in some sort of matched order?

Comment: @JeffSchaller there are the same number of files in each folder, so I want them to match so that first file of rsfMRI matches first file of DR

Comment: filenames in a directory aren't read in any guaranteed order.  e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977441/does-readdir-guarantee-an-order.  Also, sorting the filenames won't necessarily cause the pairings you want between files in the two directories.   In other words, you'll need something better than just file-order to match the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a parallel array in bash (assuming you have the same number of files in each folder):

```
#!/bin/bash

drfiles=(DR/*)
mrifiles=(rsfMRI/*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9])

for((i=0; i < ${#drfiles[@]}; i++))
do
    echo mv -- "${drfiles[i]}" "DR/dr_subject${mrifiles[i]#*_}"
done
```

The `drfiles` array contains the DR files; the `mrifiles` array contains the files from the rsfMRI directory that match the pattern: (something) (4 digits) underscore (2 digits).

We then loop through the array (keyed to the number of files in the DR folder) and print out a sample mv/rename command. The source of the rename is simply the currently-indexed DR file. The target of the rename operation is the known prefix DR/dr_subject followed by the result of pruning the corresponding MRI file of any leading text until the first underscore. If the MRI files are always named "MCU", you could simplify the rename target to: `DR/dr_subject${mrifiles[i]#rsfMRI/MCU_}`.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, but I had a question about this line in particular: "mrifiles=(rsfMRI/*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9])" ... if I wanted the last digit to be either a 1 or 3, how would I do that?  Would I write it out to be like this: "mrifiles=(rsfMRI/*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][1,3])"? or does that not make sense?

Comment: Just use: `[13]` — no comma

Comment: When I implemented that command I got: 
mv -- /home/User/Desktop/DR/dr_subject00000.nii.gz DR/dr_subjectMCU_0001_01

Comment: I want the output to be: "dr_subject0001_01"  without the MCU